# Xbox360 Universal Media Remote - out of sync?

Tags: sync, remote-control, xbox360

I have the [Universal Media Remote](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/hardware/x/xbox360universalremote/) from Microsoft, which was included with my HD-DVD package. I've been using it for over a year to watch videos/DVDs on my Xbox360 and it saved me the hassle of navigating with the game controller (which turns itself off every 5 minutes).

All of a sudden (it didn't fall or suffer any severe trauma), it does not communicate with the Xbox anymore: it is on, I replaced batteries several times, but the Xbox does not respond to commands. The TV does - volume, channels, etc. - but I need the Xbox functionality.

As far as I can see, there's no way to sync the remote with the Xbox - it lacks that small sync button that the game controllers have.
I called Microsoft Support and spoke for an hour to someone who, I guess didn't know what to do at all. Bottom line - since it's been over a year, they won't fix/replace it - I have to get a new one.Before I do (if I do), I need to know if there's anything I can do with the existing remote, and will I have the same problem with a new one (i.e. the problem is with the Xbox itself)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this post](http://www.techsupportforum.com/gaming-forum/console-gaming-support/380130-xbox-360-dvd-remote-sync-problems.html) describing similar issues. Press the Xbox 360 Guide button, go to Settings. Select System Settings, Console Settings, then Remote Control. I think those names should be correct (or close), and the last thing should be to select Xbox 360 Media Remote.

I'm not at home so I'm not able to verify this right now, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: It sounds like the remote works with other stuff, so either 1) the remote's forgotten how to talk to the Xbox, or 2) the Xbox IR is gone.  This procedure should fix #1, if it's that.

Comment: Yeah - It's tough to say if this is indeed the problem, but we should know soon enough.

Comment: OMG! It worked! THANKS! I really didn't do anything, just changed the selection from "both" to "media remote" and the remote started reacting. I changed it back - and it still works! I guess it resets the connection somehow. Thanks for saving me money/time/frustration. And Microsoft Support, if you're listening: get a SuperUser account and learn your job!

Answer (score 2):

The Universal Media Remote relies on transmitting InfraRed (IR) signals to control devices, including your Xbox360.

Now, given that your remote still can control your TV, there might be a possibility that the IR receiver on your Xbox360 is kaput. Be ready for that...

I strongly suggest before running out to buy another remote, try removing any faceplates on the XBox360, or aiming the remote really near, or getting another remote to test first.

Good luck!

Comment: Or testing your remote or another 360.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I definitely think the issue is with the console itself. The remote doesn't work even at 0 range. I may just do what Dave suggested and get another remote to test before buying. Thanks. Caliban: any idea what might have caused the IR receiver to go kaput?

Answer (score 2):

Mine just did the same thing and I just realized that it was upside down (hadn't turned it on in a very long time and just hooked it up how I had sat it on the shelf last).  When I turned it right side up, the remotes started working again. Try using the remote with the xbox in the upright and flat down positions.  The sensors may have a problem augmenting based on the way that the xbox it sitting.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem with my new Xbox 360 Slim and after some time, I figured out that the answer was in the console settings.  I documented to whole process http://www.urtech.ca/index.php/2010/12/how-to-sync-media-center-remote-to-xbox-360-slim-or-any-xbox-360-with-nov-2010-software-update/

I hope this helps!